# how to set default appearance for pdf form using python?

Tags: python, pdf, pdftk, pypdf, fdfgen

im trying to set font size and font for a pdf form using python. im currently using fdfgen and pdftk to autofill the form.I have looked around in the fdfgen library and pdftk documentation but could not find any solutions.

Comment: I've tried turning my set of data into html, used css to style it, then used libraries to convert the html to pdf. Not sure if there is a better route though.

Comment: this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949993/pdftk-form-filling-font-resize) mentions about the solution but could not find how to set it anywhere

Comment: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf Check the pdf specifications. The example on page 444 shows ```<<  /FT  /Tx      /Ff  ...% Set Multiline flag      /T  (  Silly prose )      /DA  (  0 0 1 rg  /Ti 12 Tf )      /V  (  The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse )      /AP  <<  /N  5 0 R  >>>>```. Maybe this helps!